# Expected number of balls in each box in balls and boxes experiment

Tags: probability

Forgive me if this is a duplicate, I found lots of vaguely similar questions but couldn't find an exact match.
In the balls and boxes experiment, r balls are randomly placed in n boxes. The question is, what is the expected number of balls in any given box?

What I have so far:

probability of k balls in a given box = $(\frac{1}{n})^k(\frac{n-1}{n})^{r-k}$.

Then summing this expression from k = 0 to k = r would yield the answer. But I have no idea how to get a closed form for this.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I mean, isn't it obviously $\frac rn$?

Answer (score 1):

To get the expected value, you need to multiply the probabilities with values before summing.

Instead of complicating the equation and then coming to the simple answer, we can use a simpler logic.

Each ball has 1/n chance of ending up in the given box. The probability of the second ball being in the given box doesn't change whether the first ball was in the given box or not. Hence it also has 1/n chance of ending up in the given box. In other words, your expected value is 1/n balls in the given box per ball. Multiply that with the number of balls and you get r/n

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$$(a^t+a^{t-a}b+a^{t-2}b^2+\cdots+ab^{t-1}+b^t)(a-b)=a^{t+1}-b^{t+1}$$